# How to display private Google Calendar events on my localhost start page without a webserver?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm practicing HTML/CSS/JS using localhost as a browser start page and I'd like to display the next 24 hours of my events from my Google Calendar.  However, it seems so far that a webserver (I used Python) needs to be running first.  Is there a simple way to just read these events via JavaScript?  Also, my calendar is not public.  I've checked all the documentation I could find and haven't found any solution.

I'm still learning, so I appreciate any help/suggestions you can give.  Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual goal, I think that when the calendar is publicly shared, you can access to the calendar using the calendar API with the API key. If you cannot share the calendar, for example, as one of several methods, how about using Google Apps Script and Web Apps? If these are not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, Tanaike, that does give me something to think about.  I'm creating a browser start page in order to practice my web development skills while producing something helpful.  Every time I open a browser page, it will display my upcoming events.  Maintaining a running Python webserver is still an option, but seems a little overkill for what I'm trying to do.  I could use Google Apps Script to feed data for my start page...but hoping there might be something even easier.  I'd like to keep my calendar private.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. Can you update your question by including your goal? By this, it will help users think of the solution and workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a python web server running for your application, you just have to authorize it to grab data on your behalf.

I recommend you go thru the [Python Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) to learn how to authenticate and talk with the Google APIs.

Once you have that setup and running, you can then integrate those methods to your webserver logic.

This will depend on which library or framework you are using for your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, ZektorH.  Do you know if there's any way to just retrieve events without a web server?

Comment: @Brian, yes, the method is the same, with the exception to the part where you serve it with a web-server. However, it seemed like you are already running a python web-server. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Right, I'm trying to avoid needing to run a web server.

Comment: I was able to run it from my localhost without starting up Python, thanks!